# How to create rolldown content with css?

Tags: html, css

how can i create rool down content with CSS?

```
TEXT

INFOINFOINFO
INFOINFOINFO
```

the TEXT will be always seen but the INFO will show when the pointer click on TEXT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a pure CSS solution using CSS property `content`.

If you are interested to know more about `content` you can read this [useful article](https://css-tricks.com/css-content/).

```css
.txt span{
  display:none;
}
.txt:hover:after {
  display:block;
  content:'info info info';
}
```

```html
<p class="txt">text<p>
```

Or you can use a more "classic" approach, where instead you show hide a `span` tag:

```css
.txt span {
  display: none;
}

.txt:hover span {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<p class="txt">text<span>some information</span><p>
```

---

Pro and Cons IMO:

First approach:

- You can keep your HTML cleaner.
- Info text won't be visible to Search Engines (could be a PRO or CON it depends of your use case).
- IE < 8 do not support `content` property.

Second approach:

- You can keep your "information" in the HTML.
- Info will be visible to Search Engines.

Comment: @MichaelFlorian do you also need an animation effect?. I could provide you an example if you need it. Please let me know.

Comment: Thank you for your help! :) I have a lil problem with animation. I set .text span { transition-duration:0.2s;  }but the text in it is showing much faster than 0.2s, and i dont know why.

Comment: @MichaelFlorian ok, please create a new question and post your source code there. I will do my best to help. Please link your question here so I can found it :)

Answer (score 0):

check this

```css
span{
  display:none;
}
p.head:hover span{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<p class="head">text<span>info info info ifno</span><p>
```

Comment: And what if i want animation for that? I can make it but.. will be there any problem with that?

Answer (score 0):

when pointer click.
here just a little modification from previous answer

```
<style>
p:active:after{
content:"info info";
}
</style>
<p>text</p>
```

Comment: This would applies to all P tags in the page, not sure if it is really wanted. Instead better use a class or id selector, for only selectively apply this effect.

Comment: thats not a real problem for me, i have made new .css file for specific "tab" where i need this